# Check textarea with php

Tags: php, textarea

I have a textarea field and want to add a text or php code when the field is empty and if the field is not empty to add another php code. For example:

if the field is empty>do something.....else>do something...

I'm not good at php, so I'll be glad for any help.
Thanks.

p.s.Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're posting this from a form then you can do the following.

I'll write this out the long way so it's easier to understand:

```
if (!empty($_POST['TEXTAREA_NAME']){
     // If the textarea is set then do something here
} else {
     // If it is NOT set it then it will do the code here
}
```

Comment: You need to use `empty` as well as `isset` to meet @Vendeta's criteria. I have added it for you.

Comment: ok, maybe my question silly but what I have to type in TEXTAREA_NAME (the text area html "name" attrybute or sth else)?

Comment: i've got a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']

never mind... I find it... Thank you for quick replies

Comment: I've amended the answer to fix that.

Comment: @Treffynnon you don't need isset with empty. Fixed that for you both.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel As a rule is it better just to use empty() then?

Comment: sure. it makes your code 2 times shorter. However, empty() may fail you with literal `0`. I'd prefer to compare an outside variable with empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['texarea_name']) && !empty($_POST['texarea_name']) ? 'textarea not empty' : 'texarea is empty'; ?>
```

Comment: it works but i checked the above as an answer because it is easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

To test if outside variable is empty or not, you can just compare it with empty string

```
if ( $_POST['text'] === '') {
     echo 'there was something';
} else {
     echo 'nothing to say';
}
```